# Should low-rep users really see who voted for deletion?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

When a question was closed, the list of who voted for closure is shown only to users with close/reopen privileges, at least it says so in the banner - and that makes sense to me.

I was then quite surprised today when I voted for *deletion of an answer* [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354498/can-you-force-the-user-to-run-your-gcc-compiled-c-program-as-admin) (where the answer didn't fit to the question<sup>1</sup>) and later got a comment on the question *directed to me personally*, from a user with just above 100 rep, saying I'm a coward for deleting their answer.

I looked at the banner that shows who voted for *deletion* and indeed, it does not say "only visible to (some group of users)".

Does that make sense? What is the rationale behind it? In my mind, it should be similar to close votes, so only other people with the "access to moderation tools" privilege should see who voted. Maybe it could be shown to users with the close vote privilege, I don't know, but definitely not to low-rep users who aren't fully familiar yet with how things work, because it is of no use other than allowing them to post annoyed comments like this or perhaps go on to downvote other posts by the delete-voters in "retaliation".

While one can still see these things in the timeline, I assume annoyed low-rep users are less likely to go there or even know they could find it there. My point is that we don't have to also put up a signpost that says: "Feeling frustrated? Here are some users you could target your anger towards!".

**Update:** I now created [a feature request for this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426960/low-rep-users-should-not-see-usernames-of-people-who-voted-for-deletion-of-their) - in a separate post so it won't get pre-polluted with the discussion about this particular deletion.

---

<sub>**1:** Turned out that it's not so clear after all whether it fit to the question or not. I still think it technically talked about a different thing than what was asked but it seems it could be interpreted otherwise. Therefore it's possible that deletion was not actually warranted in this case and I will probably be a bit more reluctant with the use of this vote in the future, but that's beside the point of my concern, especially because I'm not the only person to "blame" for deletion and in fact the third voter voted *after* the answer was edited while I voted *before*, yet the poster directed the comment to *me*.</sub>

Comment: Deletion is rare; they are when a question is completely unsalvagable. If that's the case, then, in truth, it's more like that the OP knows that. Why are you concerned that they can see who deleted their question when close votes are much more common and they are public too.

Comment: It's about deleting an answer, not a question. Please read my post again because I explained why I'm concerned - it sparks unnecessary personal attacks.

Comment: Note that the users who closed a question aren't *completely* masked. Just obscured - the participants in closure are still visible in the timeline. There is still transparency in the end, just slightly harder. I'd agree that it makes sense to have a similar thing for deletions, though, just to try and prevent such attacks like this one.

Comment: Yes I know it's not hidden entirely but the kind of user who calls rep "credits" and is resentful for deletion of an irrelevant answer probably doesn't know to look in the timeline for the voters anyway. That's why I think we just don't have to shove this in their face.

Comment: Why was the answer deleted?

Comment: @Dharman Because it missed the point of the question entirely. It's better now but I voted before that edit happened. "not even partially answering the actual question" is cause for deletion as far as I know, and nothing in that answer (at least in its original form) was applicable to the question. The question was about a C++ program compiled with MinGW that acts as kind of an installer and how to get it to require elevation, not about MSI or bypassing UAC or elevating already-running threads.

Comment: *"It's about deleting an answer, not a question."* Personally, I don't really see that as a distinction here. You can, however, replace "question" with "post" in my [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426953/should-low-rep-users-really-see-who-voted-for-deletion?noredirect=1#comment976355_426953) though to make it less specific to questions, and "more relevant" to your post here.

Comment: @ThomA I meant that while deleting questions is rare, deleting answers is not so rare.

Comment: Not to excuse the offending comment, but are you sure you are using delete votes the way they are intended? Wrong answers should usually be downvoted, but not deleted. Only if the post is completely off-topic, a delete vote is warranted.

Comment: @BDL See my comment on E_net4's answer. I am downvoting when it is "wrong" but voting for deletion when it is "irrelevant", such as here "answering a similar but different question not really overlapping the actual question". I saw a clear distinction between the topic the question was about and the topic the answer was about, that's why I felt deletion was warranted. In this specific example I can however also see that not for everyone this distinction is as clear as it was for me - but that's why it requires multiple people with the same view on things to actually go through with it, no?

Comment: @BDL Deletion is part of curation. While we are not supposed to flag poor or wrong answers as NAA, because reviewers may not be able to verify the correctness and reasons, we have ability to cast delete votes on downvoted answers and that includes deleting wrong or poor answers.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Your view doesn't align well with what the help center description of the [close vote privilege says](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) in the "When should I delete answers" section. Deleting answers that are wrong is not one of the reason to delete them.

Comment: @BDL Are we reading the same description, because that is exactly what I said. Deleting answers that are beyond improvement - that would be wrong or poor answers, and answers that don't attempt to answer the question. If the answer completely misses the point of the question then it does not answer the question. There is no attempt here.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I just realized there is another fine distinction here which is up to interpretation: While the _poster_ may have attempted to write an answer that answers the question, the _answer itself_ does _not_ attempt to answer the question (it attempts to answer a different question). Hmmm. (I would say an answer that attempts to answer the question would have been for example "the only way is to rename your file to install.exe" - which is still wrong because there are other, better ways and it no longer works in Win10+ but it is now an attempt to answer the right question.)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar There is disagreement as to whether there is an attempt in the answer here. Fundamentally speaking, it is about requiring the user to run an application as an administrator, and the answer has that in mind. There are certain subtleties that make an expert say it has nothing to do with what was asked, but I don't think we're doing any good by making that a basis for deletion.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: An answer that is wrong is not necessarily beyond improvement. Beyond improvement means for me that no amount of editing can fix the problem. I don't see that in this answer. It's at least related to the question asked, although it doesn't fully answer the question.

Comment: @E_net4 I am reading that answer again and again, and I cannot see how it even remotely answers the question.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: If the question is "How can I do X" and an answer is "You can't do X", even if the answer is flat-out wrong as it appears to be in this case I still think it counts as an attempt to answer the question. I've seen many "How can I do X" questions where the most correct answer is "You can't do X".

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk The question asks how to do X and the answer is you cannot do XX. You can absolutely request that application needs to be run as administrator and the question shows the appropriate steps taken to do that. But for some reason it does not work for the OP, I don't use GCC so I don't know where is the problem and why the resulting application is not showing shield icon and does not trigger UAC. So if anything the question might lack MCVE, but the answer is definitely not "You cannot do that".

Comment: This should probably be made into a feature-request; low rep users should absolutely not see who deleted their question on the post page itself; it only serves to encourage targeted harassment. Arguably such votes should not visible to low rep users in the timeline, either.

Comment: @TylerH Should I create a new meta post for that then or should I "convert" this one into a feature request?

Comment: @CherryDT I would recommend making a new one. That way you don't invalidate the answer below and you don't distract with a specific example about whether that example is correctly deleted or not.

Comment: Done: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426960/low-rep-users-should-not-see-usernames-of-people-who-voted-for-deletion-of-their

Answer (score 11):

If we were to focus primarily on the question asked here, I'd say that **users should not have to** be able to see the list of users who deleted the answer. Regardless of who did it, the right way to appeal is to cast a flag for moderator on the post itself. If the deletion notice at the top of the deleted answer does not include this recommendation to the post author, then I would say it should.

---

That would be it, but there are other side concerns here that I believe should not be overlooked:

Three users voted to delete an honest attempt at an answer, which is a bit contrary to the principle suggested in [the page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) that was even linked in response to the deleted answer's author.

> Answer posts that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
>
> - commentary on the question or other answers
> - asking another, different question
> - "thanks!" or "me too!"-type responses
> - exact duplicates of other answers
> - barely more than a link to an external site (i.e. the actual answer is not included in the post)
> - not even a partial answer to the actual question

When faced with the question *"Can you force the user to run your GCC compiled C program as admin?"*, saying that *"there is no way in Windows to make apps always run in Admin mode"*, as limited and badly explained as it was, *still stood as attempting to answer the question*. And since the answer is not even considered dangerous (though there is a bit of controversy on how such answers should be handled), the urge to delete the answer can indeed be put to question. Delete votes are not super-downvotes.

Nevertheless, I will be very clear on this: **none of the actions on the answer excuse the author** from verbally assaulting voters like that. Comments of that nature must be flagged appropriately, so that further repercussions can be applied later on. Circling back to the first paragraph, I would definitely be inclined towards hiding the names from the notice to post authors, in a similar   fashion to how it's done in question closure notices.

Comment: In my mind it was "not even a partial answer to the actual question", because the answer was assuming the question was about bypassing security measures to elevate a running process, when in fact it was about marking an executable (that doesn't yet run) as requiring elevation (so the user either confirms that or can't run it) - that was obvious from the example with the shield icon. Later with the edit (after I voted), it then sounded like it was assuming that this was about MSIs. Neither of those are what the question stated. That's why I (and apparently two others) felt the vote was fine.

Comment: I do see how this is a matter of perspective though (and technical background and how one interprets the things written from a specific technical point of view), but that's why it's good that it requires _three_ votes to actually delete an answer, not one!

Comment: Generally the need for three votes would reduce the chance for mistakes, that much I agree. The interpretation made for deletion is hard to follow though. Usually one shouldn't need to make such a fine grained distinction, and the "fundamental" part is still there. We have to think what exactly we are gaining by just deleting attempts at answering the question, especially in a question which arrived only yesterday and did not attract a good quality answer yet.

Comment: Side note - "especially in a question which arrived only yesterday and did not attract a good quality answer yet" - that's because the question was originally a duplicate, it _should not get answers_ in fact. Then it got an edit including the should-actually-be-correct solution, which turned it into a question that is not reproducible and/or missing details and therefore still not properly answerable, which is why I commented and didn't answer.

Comment: So, the duplicate has indeed been contested with an edit, though I don't see any close votes as missing an MRE. Until the fate of the question is established, the rest of the rationale would stand. If it _is_ eventually closed, that sounds like much less of a reason to be concerned about bad answers which will likely be ignored. Things would flow in good motion either way. :) (Without having voted to delete the answer, we wouldn't have tasted the wrath of that unreasonable user, but if we could predict future bad behavior, we would be so much better off in general.)

Comment: When curating, should your main focus be to try and keep content around, or do you try and get content gone? That is a question everyone should ask themselves and periodically repeat the question as over time you might start to disagree with yourself. Depending on which side of the fence you position yourself on, you will differ how you choose to interpret the guidelines. It makes meta discussions a little... unproductive. I remember an old Hanna-Barbera cartoon where two people were just continuously shooting back the same bullet at each other.

Comment: @Gimby honestly, seems like both of those are the wrong thing to ask yourself. The correct thing to ask is "What actions will improve the knowledge base". Some times it's leaving something in, other times it's removing something. There is no *one* path. Both deletion and preservations are valid actions actions and are supposed to serve a greater goal.

Comment: @Gimby Picking the same side without adding more to the discussion would indeed be unproductive. Save for any eventual changes of mind, my statements on the subject have been made and I do not intend to repeat them. Besides, we all know it's [Duck Season](https://youtu.be/9-k5J4RxQdE).

Comment: "still stood as attempting to answer the question" It doesn't matter in case the answer is factually incorrect and misleading. We have no obligation to save crap. Nobody will benefit from it. There isn't some goal of SO that goes "we seek to be an archive of failed attempts to correctly answer technical questions". And for that reason it is no big deal to delete incorrect answers. Use common sense over some "but they _tried_ to answer" meta mindset.

Comment: Additionally we may sometimes delete heavily down-voted posts just to save the user from accumulating a ton of them when they already received the message.

Comment: @VLAZ the elusive middle ground :) You're correct, of course. But I do wonder how many people have which mindset.

Comment: Most of this answer seems related to a separate issue than what OP is asking about. Whether the answer was correctly deleted here is irrelevant (to this Meta question). What's relevant is whether a low-rep user should be able to see who voted to delete their question.

Comment: My personal observations from being a recent low-rep user on other stackexchange sites, is hiding who votes for delete does more harm than good. The fact that it showed up spared quite a bit of drama because everybody could see which moderator deleted something. Hiding it would have given fuel to the fire that there was a rogue moderator.

Comment: @Joshua There was no rogue moderator here, so let's not reduce this to a red herring. Regardless of where you side on whether the answer should have been deleted or not, we are not better off for having made the names visible.

Comment: @E_net4: It's not a red herring. Hiding the who deleted would have resulted in people believing there was one.

Comment: @Joshua I mean, people complain about downvotes as well. It's a matter of educating them not to make unfounded assumptions. Those who do usually don't get far around these parts.

Comment: @Joshua Nothing would be hidden. It just wouldn't be nailed to a sign on the front door. You might have to click once or twice more to see who closed the question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: Explain please.

Comment: @Joshua just like how close votes are handled. The names of close voters are removed from the notification. Not from the timeline. So, it's always possible to review who close voted. Just not immediately obvious by glancing at the post.

Comment: @Joshua Basically what VLAZ said -- you'd have to visit the timeline of the question to see who deleted the post, but it's still there. If you really want to hunt down the deleters with pitchforks and torches. Or you could, you know, *edit* the post to remove the reasons for deletion, so that you can flag it for undeletion.