# Low-rep users should not see usernames of people who voted for deletion of their question or answer in the banner

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

In this feature request I would like to propose that the usernames of delete-voters get hidden from low-rep users in the deletion banner, similarly to how the usernames of close-voters already are not shown in the banner unless the viewer already reached the close-vote privilege level themselves.

[image: screenshot highlighting the usernames in the banner]

It is open to discussion at which privilege level the delete-voter usernames should be shown there (I could think of either 10k at which the viewers get delete-voting rights themselves or 3k at which they start seeing close-voters), and also whether such votes should also be hidden in the timeline from low-rep users or not (currently close-voters' usernames *are* visible there).

The rationale is that this information is not useful to low-rep users anyway and in fact can only do harm because it facilitates personal attacks in comments or retalation actions such as mass-downvoting against one or all of the users who voted for deletion. Plus, a similar policy is already in place for close votes so it would make sense to apply it to delete votes as well.

(Original meta discussion [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426953/should-low-rep-users-really-see-who-voted-for-deletion).)

Comment: Hm - I thought I was doing the right thing as perhaps "discussion" was the wrong format to begin with and a user suggested opening a feature request for it (that comment got upvoted several times as well). After all, half of the discussion there then was about whether or not a delete vote _in that particular case_ was even warranted. @really-experienced-people: What is the right thing to do now? Nothing? Delete the other discussion? Delete this request? Edit something? Something else? Sorry if I made a mess out of things now...

Comment: @Gimby Yeah, this is a valid FR in its own right, and the discussion was getting distracted by whether the specific example given by OP was rightfully deleted in the first place. It never would have survived being converted to a FR in-place.

Comment: @CherryDT To Gimby's point, perhaps you can edit the discussion post to focus more on whether the answer was rightfully deleted and whether your received harassment there was justified.

Comment: That those names should be hidden for low-rep users is a good idea, but I wonder if there are actual use-cases where a user with higher rep really needs those names. Is tagging all of them in a comment or chat something that is currently done and something we want to happen?

Comment: @Tom transparency. I don't see a compelling reason to completely hide information about regular users' moderation actions.

Comment: @VLAZ Mods still can see those information. And you can still see the currently available data in the user profile.

Comment: @Tom Yes, but there's no harm in allowing users of sufficient rep/privilege to be able to identify and report on potential abuse when necessary. Without seeing who cast the votes, there's no way to identify a pattern of abuse.

Comment: TBH, I don't know why we have needed a discussion in the first place; We can discuss under a post tagged with FR :/ I wanna close the other thread in favor of this one, but I'll leave it just as a suggestion: "consider closing the other thread as a dupe of this :)". I mean, I don't want to be called a coward for closing a question, lol, Cheers.

Comment: @M-- Because I just didn't realize that a FR was the way to go. I think I never opened one before.

Comment: More generally, it would be nice to have a smoother way to transition from a discussion to a corresponding feature-request (or bug report).

Comment: Is this a common problem? I've deleted a few posts, and only rarely gotten any follow up comments, and I don't recall a single time the comments were abusive. We can already flag abusive users, so if this is not a common problem, I would be inclined to not hide information.

Comment: @cigien hard to give accurate numbers of - revenge votes aren't something we can accurately trace but are likely to be one of the more common expressions of "disagreement" with deletion. However, we (and that is more on SE but we the community largely approve) have decided to do this protection for closures. I don't see any problem with extending it to deletions. Basically the same considerations apply. IMO, there is no "minimum level of abuse" that curators have to be subjected to in order to consider this given that 1. we know curators are attacked over this 2. we've a similar mitigation

Comment: @VLAZ I agree with doing this for closures. They're more common, and I am aware that close-voters do get attacked for closing posts fairly regularly. It's just that I haven't heard of this being much of an issue with deletions. I definitely think there should be a "minimum level of abuse" consideration before information is hidden/made more difficult to find.